# what to use to check in between comparisons in c?

Tags: c

need to make a c program that will get the current time of pc and display if its traffic or not.

**Traffic every : 7:00am - 10:00am && 17pm - 19pm**

need help in time comparisons. im using if else.

if ((mytime > 7 && mytime < 10) && (mytime > 17 && mytime < 19))

Comment: Well, that should probably be an "or" at the top level (the middle operator). You need to check if the current time is in the morning *or* in the evening. Obviously the current time will never be in the morning *and* in the evening at the same time. Also, it's unclear what the type of your `mytime` variable is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `||` (OR) instead of `&&` (AND). Or it will never work.

And to get the hour, do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *now_tm = localtime(&now);
    int hour = now_tm->tm_hour;

    if ((hour > 7 && hour < 10) || (hour > 17 && hour < 19))
        printf("traffic\n");
    else
        printf("smooth\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: uhh ohh. tried it. its 8:46 am in the morning but its printing smooth. It should be traffic

Comment: Inside the if you are printing traffic and in the else your are printing smooth, right?

Comment: @Nina_Jenner How do you represent hours and minutes in your time? The above code assumes that `mytime` just contains the hour.

Comment: You can convert hours to minutes (*60) and work just with minutes.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
time_t mytime;
mytime time (NULL);

if ((mytime >= 7 && mytime <= 10) && (mytime >= 17 && mytime <=19))
{
printf ("traffic");
}
else
{
printf ("smooth");
}

getchar();
return 0;
}

//heres part of my code.

Comment: im already ok with the time. Seems the only trouble im getting is

if ((mytime > 7 && mytime < 10) || (mytime > 17 && mytime < 19))


/ sorry for bad english

Comment: I updated the answer. You can't compare time_t mytime directly with a int.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use seconds (source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t now;
  struct tm newyear;
  struct tm _7am;
  struct tm _10am;
  struct tm _5pm;
  struct tm _7pm;
  double mytime;
  double s_7am, s_10am, s_5pm, s_7pm;

  time(&now);

  newyear = *localtime(&now);
  newyear.tm_hour = 0; newyear.tm_min = 0; newyear.tm_sec = 0;
  newyear.tm_mon = 0;  newyear.tm_mday = 1;

  _7am = *localtime(&now);
  _7am.tm_hour = 7; _7am.tm_min = 0; _7am.tm_sec = 0;
  s_7am = difftime(mktime(&_7am),mktime(&newyear));

  _10am = *localtime(&now);
  _10am.tm_hour = 10; _10am.tm_min = 0; _10am.tm_sec = 0;
  s_10am = difftime(mktime(&_10am),mktime(&newyear));

  _5pm = *localtime(&now);
  _5pm.tm_hour = 17; _5pm.tm_min = 0; _5pm.tm_sec = 0;
  s_5pm = difftime(mktime(&_5pm),mktime(&newyear));

  _7pm = *localtime(&now);
  _7pm.tm_hour = 19; _7pm.tm_min = 0; _7pm.tm_sec = 0;
  s_7pm = difftime(mktime(&_7pm),mktime(&newyear));

  mytime = difftime(now,mktime(&newyear));

  if ((mytime > s_7am && mytime < s_10am) || (mytime > s_5pm && mytime < s_7pm)){
     printf("Traffic!");
  }else{
     printf("Smooth...");
  }


  return 0;
}
```